# Python loops and dynamic stacks

Tags: python, loops, matrix

I want to create a loop. This loop is supposed to do an iteration. The only thing I need is the last iteration it does. I was wondering whether I could create a dynamic stack for that, so that I don't define a matrix beforehand, which uses memory. How could I do that?

Comment: Maybe you can put up some code you've tried that would make this clearer?

Comment: Why do you need a stack? Just use a variable and overwrite it in each iteration. At the end it will store the value from the last iteration.

Comment: We need to see some code here. Perhaps the "reversed" function is what you are looking for, but it is impossible to tell without seeing any code.

Comment: Ah, yes. You`re right. My problem can be solved with simply overwriting the variables. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want the result of the last iteration?

If so, this should do the trick:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

j=0
for i in range(13):
    # with each iteration j grows by 37
    j+=37

    # note: Accessing values from last iterations like below can be hard to accomplish
    #       and may require more helper variables or finally a list.
    print("step " + str(i) + ": \tj grew from " + str(j-37) + " to " + str(j) + ".")
# At this point j got overwritten 13 times and holds the value of 13*37. 
print("Finally j holds the value " + str(j) + ".")
```

If I got you wrong, and you do really just want to do the last 'iteration' you basically do not iterate. You would remove the loop and would set i to the last value of the iteration before the highly complex calculation within the old loop:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

j=0
i=12  # the last value of range(13)
# the old loop:
j+=37
print("'step' " + str(i) + ": \tj grew from " + str(j-37) + " to " + str(j) + ".")
# end of the old loop
# At this point j got overwritten one time and holds the value of 1*37. 
print("finally j holds the value " + str(j) + ".")
```

The Second part is likely trivial and just for the sake of completeness.
I hope this answers your question.
Please consider code examples the next time you ask something on a Q&A board.